# CSS <li> fix text out of line

Tags: css

Consider this style :

[image]

I'm trying to make the prices appear in line after the price: but as you can see it goes up well it's AJAX selection, and here is the code:

```
<ol class="currently">    
    <li>
        <a href="html" class="btn-remove" title="Remove This Item">Remove This Item</a>                  
        <span class="label">Price:</span> 
        <span class="price">$22.00</span> - <span class="price">$35.00</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

CSS:

```
.block-layered-nav .currently .label {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Wheres the CSS that applies to ol.currently?  Where is the CSS that applies to the class .price.  You've only provided one tiny snippet, we need the whole picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because of

```
margin: 10px 0 0 0;
```

in your CSS. Change it to

```
margin: 0 0 0 0;
```

or

```
margin: 0;
```

Comment: or add 10px margin to top of span.price

Comment: yeah or give same class to all span.. ;)

Comment: @Sid M yes it was it thank you Sid I don't know how I missed it been looking for some time

Comment: @Dpeif that's the funny thing I did and it didn't work remove margin or putting 0 worked

Answer (score 1):

Just remove margin in your css.